# Nginx load balancer websocket issue

Tags: nginx, websocket, load-balancing

I'm new in NGINX and WebSocket systems but as per my project requirements I need to check some complex things to finish.

I'm trying to create one example using NGINX, which handles my WebSocket (Port: 1234) and HTTP Requests (Port: 80) using same Url (load balancer url).

I'm using three NGINX server, one as Load Balancer (10.0.0.163) and other two as my application server where I have installed my real APIs, 10.0.0.152 and 10.0.0.154 respectively. Right now, I have configured WebSocket on my application servers.

As per above configuration, my all requests will pass over 10.0.0.163 (load balancer) and it's proxy setting will pass the request (HTTP/WebSocket) to my application server (10.0.0.152/154).

Note : Each application server contain separate Nginx, php, websocket

Here is default (location : /etc/nginx/sites-available/) file for 10.0.0.154 server, which handles WebSocket and HTTP requests on same domain.

```
server{
    listen 80;
        charset UTF-8;
        root /var/www;
        index index.html index.htm index.php
        server_name localhost 10.0.0.154 ;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ @proxy;    autoindex on;
    }
    location @proxy{
        proxy_pass http://wb1;
    }
    location =/ {
                proxy_pass http://wb;       
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_buffers 8 16k;
                proxy_buffer_size 32k;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade; 
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        Referer                 $http_referer;
        proxy_redirect off;

        }

}
```

Following is default file (location : /etc/nginx/sites-available/) for load balancer at 10.0.0.163.

```
upstream wb{
    server 10.0.0.154;
    server 10.0.0.152;
}

server{
    listen 80;
        charset UTF-8;
        root /var/www;
        index index.html index.htm index.php
        server_name 10.0.0.163 ;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ @proxy;    autoindex on;
    }
    location @proxy{
        proxy_pass http://wb;
    }
    location =/ {
                proxy_pass http://wb;       
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_buffers 8 16k;
                proxy_buffer_size 32k;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade; 
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        Referer                 $http_referer;
        proxy_redirect off;

        }

}
```

I found that, load balancer is working properly for HTTP requests but it's unable to proceed my WebSocket requests to my application server.

I don't know what I'm missing here .. If you guys can help me out would be great appriciate

Comment: What version of nginx do you use?

Comment: @VBart I am using nginx-1.4.1 version.

Comment: @VBart -- After debugging the code, I get connection established and disconnected after 30 sec. I get error "Peer not responding."

Comment: Looks like that you haven't configured timeouts: [proxy_read_timeout](http://nginx.org/r/proxy_read_timeout) and [proxy_write_timeout](http://nginx.org/r/proxy_write_timeout). What's in the error log?

Comment: @VBart -- Thanks for replied. We tried proxy_read_timeout but it did not work. User send websocket connection to  LB(Load Balancer) server. LB send data to application server to node.js (websocket) program. Websocket do handshake as well but unable to send frame to user via LB.

Comment: @VBart --(updated) Thanks for replied. We tried proxy_read_timeout but it did not work. User send websocket connection to  LB(Load Balancer) server. LB(Nginx) send data to application server(Nginx) to node.js (websocket) program. Websocket do handshake as well but unable to send frame to user via LB. It is working fine if we remove LB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seen your configuration looks proper. I think you should check your load balancer & your application server configuration or versions. It maybe problem of incompatibility.

Comment: Your right @sanjay... I checked both versions of LB and application. I solved this issue.

Comment: @Rizvan what is the solution?

Comment: Version mismatch with loadbalancer nginx and application nginx.